# I want to check that my function is returning a pointer that's pointing to the right object

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out if the function returns pointing to the right structure. And that it is holding the right piece of data.

This is what I mean, I want to figure out if `function` is working correctly. The criteria for a working function is that adds a new item to a doubly linked list. And returns a pointer to that doubly linked list item.

```
struct dataStructure* test;
test = function(&data);
```

I guess the gist of my question comes down to is there a way to get that piece of data from the pointer?
I have tried a few different comparison operations and gotten only errors. Or even just a resource on structures and pointers you found helpful.

I apologize if this is a poorly put together question, please let me know what you guys look for in good questions in the future.
Thank you

Comment: .....depends  what function() does.  In general, debuggers can dereference through pointers and display the data pointed to.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, I don't understand *how* you would like to check "[...] working correctly". Do you have criteria to check?

Comment: If you have the criteria, what have you tried to check it so far? Please show us some code, and point to where is does not what you expect it to do. -- For this you need to provide a [example]; please take the [tour] and read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the function, if it doesn't allocate memory then it is just a matter of checking if `data == test` after calling the function, but if it does allocate memory and a point to that memory is returned, then it is a new object and there is nothing to check, unless you really want to be sure, which could be the case when there is no way to know what the function does. The only other situation is if the function changes to another object pointed by a member of that object, then again it is a matter of checking if  e.g. `data.next == test`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case function does call malloc() which does create allocate memory but I guess I'm a little confused by what you mean that there is nothing to check? Do you mean that the function isn't returning anything that enables checking for errors? Or that there is no point in checking for errors?

Comment: By "nothing to check" I meant it would "obviously" be a new object and said check wouldn't be needed, unless there is no way to know what the function does. I have edited the answer to make that clear.